# How to remove default button style in android

Tags: java, android

[image]

Above is my button and i want to remove default shadow also, I have successfully removed background but shadow is still there below is my xml code

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/create_account"
    android:id="@+id/buttonCreateAccount"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@null"
    style=""
    android:shadowRadius="@null"
    android:drawableBottom="@null"
/>
```

Comment: use your own custom style

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use following style

```
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
```